# Adding to a data array externally PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to figure out how to add to a PHP data array externally using PHP.

Say if this array, below. Was in a file called Index.php

```
$data=array("user1"=>array("url"=>"user1.pdf","password"=>"pass1"), 
            "user2"=>array("url"=>"user2.php","password"=>"pass2"));
```

and I wanted to add third user using a different Php file taking inputs from somewhere else to insert into the url, password and user namespace.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

$data['user3']=array("url"=>"user3.pdf","password"=>"pass3")

Answer (score 0):

If you need it from *different file*, then the simplest way is to include the other file, which adds users to $data.

**index.php**

```
$data = array(
            "user1"=>array("url"=>"user1.pdf","password"=>"pass1"), 
            "user2"=>array("url"=>"user2.php","password"=>"pass2")
);
```

**other_file.php**

```
include "other_file.php";
$data["user3"] = array("url"=>"user3.php","password"=>"pass3");
// or 
array_push($data, array("user3" => array("url"=>"user3.php","password"=>"pass3"));
```

Are you sure you need that other file?

Comment: Yeah. I'm creating a system where you upload a file and specify a Username and a password and if you type in the correct username and password, it will redirect you there.

Answer (score 0):

I believe include_once() or require_once() should do the trick.

```
include_once('index.php');
array_push($data,"user3"=>array("url"=>"user3.pdf","pass"=>"123"));
```

include_once or require_once functions are similar to executing that file once and continuing further. https://www.php.net/include_once
Alternatively, php now allows for object-oriented programming, so if you are familiar with it you can take a shot at that

Comment: This is what I have:

      array_push($data, $_POST['username'] =>array("url" =>"uploadedfiles/" . $_FILES['file']['name'] ,"pass"=>$_POST['password']));

and where I'm adding it to I have:

    include "upload_file.php";
    $data = array(
                "user1"=>array("url"=>"user1.pdf","password"=>"pass1"), 
                "user2"=>array("url"=>"user2.php","password"=>"pass2")
    );

However, I'm getting a error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?